# Android system doesn't go to recovery mode

Tags: android, updating, ota

I wrote some code

```
public boolean installPackage(Context context, File packageFile) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "installPackage()");
    try {
        RecoverySystem.installPackage(context, packageFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "InstallPackageException", e);
        return false;
    }

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "installPackage return true");
    return true;
}
```

This line: `RecoverySystem.installPackage(context, packageFile);` should reboot system in recovery mode and install ota package.

But sometimes system doesnt boot in recovery mode, system only do reboot and update file is not installed.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you define the required permissions? (And I assume that the app should be a System app to do this)

Comment: Yes, I defined permissions, application is a system app. Sometimes system go to recovery and update file is applied. But sometimes system only rebooting.

Comment: Did you add `android:sharedUserId="com.google.uid.shared"` in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Should I add "com.google.uid.shared" or should I change this line to other?

Comment: Add `android:sharedUserId="com.google.uid.shared"` in your `<manifest>` tag.

Comment: I added but, it didn't help